# How to display html table on target JSP Page

Tags: html, jsp, html-table

I have on html page which take inputs from user and one jsp page for displaying the output. There is one table in the html page where users are asked to enter some data, table row might dynamically change as per the user. Now, how would I display it on the target JSP Page. Below is the code sample of my html page:

```
           <tr>
            <td>Menu</td>

            <td><input type="text" id="menu_name" placeholder="Menu">
                <input type="text" id="menu_quan" placeholder="Quantity"> <input
                type="text" id="menu_amt" placeholder="Amount"> <input
                type="button" class="add-menu" value="Add"> <!-- <input type="button" class="del-menu" value="Delete"> -->
                <hr>
                <table id="menu_tbl1" border="1px collapsable"
                    style="display:; border-collapse: collapse;" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Menu</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Select</th>

                    </tr>
                    <tbody id="menu_tbl">
                        <tr>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>

                </table>
                </td>
        </tr>
```

Suppose I want to display the above table in the target JSP page, how should I do this.

Here is the screenshot for html page:

[image]

I have to display the same table in jsp page except the column Select.

Comment: And? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @JozefChocholacek. I am very much new to JSP, so right now I have not progress in this.

Comment: I would suggest typing `jsp tutorial` into Google, picking one of the results, carefully reading it and trying the examples. This (how to display a table) is usually somewhere around 3rd or 4th chapter of the tutorial.

Comment: What is your requirement ? Do you want to show table in jsp ?

Comment: @AvijitBarua.. I want to display the above table (look attached image in my question) as it is on (with data) on the targeted jsp page. The attached image is on html page which after submission will display the data on the target JSP Page.

Comment: Please post your servlet code !